# Search directories containing numbers larger than a certain threshold in their name

Tags: find, ls, wildcards, search, seq

This is the command that I have and would like to modify with an additional condition:

```
find /home/user/backups/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3 -name "*~EEEE000.tif" -print
```

This is the output of `ls /home/user/backups/`:

```
backup20170101_somerandomstring
backup20170115_somerandomstring
backup20170230_somerandomstring
backup20170305_somerandomstring
backup20170408_somerandomstring
backup20170521_somerandomstring
.
.
.
backup20190111_somerandomstring
backup20190130_somerandomstring
backup20190209_somerandomstring
backup20190301_somerandomstring
backup20190303_somerandomstring
backup20190311_somerandomstring
backup20190313_somerandomstring
backup20190412_somerandomstring
.
.
.
backup20200102_somerandomstring
backup20200103_somerandomstring
backup20200105_somerandomstring
backup20200110_somerandomstring
.
.
.
```

I only want to search directories that were generated after 2019-03-10. So this can be easily thought of as **directories** **which in their name have numbers larger than `20190310` right after the word `backup`**.

I can thin of `seq` but do not know how to use it alongside find. And I am sure there are better options out there.

```
seq -f "backup%1.0f" 20190310 20200131
```

Comment: Does the date in the directories name match the field "Birth time" returned by applying `stat` to the directories?

Comment: @PauloTomé I thought of using `newerBt` in `find` but I am using a filesystem that does not store birth time at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `zsh` shell, the filename globbing pattern `<n-m>` matches numbers in the range `n` to `m` inclusively.

The pattern

```
/home/user/backups/backup<20190311->_*
```

would match all names in `/home/user/backups` that start with the string `backup` and is immediately followed by a number that is `20190311` or larger, and then an underscore and possibly more characters.

To match only directories:

```
/home/user/backups/backup<20190311->_*(/)
```

Using this with your original `find` command:

```
find /home/user/backups/backup<20190311->_*(/) \
    -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -name "*~EEEE000.tif" -print
```

This would search each directory that the glob matches for names of files or directories ending with `~EEEE000.tif` (at specific directory depths).  It would print the found pathnames.  The search depths have been adjusted to account for the extra depth of the search path roots.

Without `find`, and only printing names of regular files:

```
print -rC1 -- \
    /home/user/backups/backup<20190311->_*/*'~EEEE000.tif'(.ND) \
    /home/user/backups/backup<20190311->_*/*/*'~EEEE000.tif'(.ND)
```

This would also resolve symbolic links to directories in the paths though.

Comment: Sounds like the OP would then want: `find /home/user/backups/backup<20190311->_*(/) -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -name "*~EEEE000.tif" -print`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, I misread the question. Yes, you are correct. Will update.

Comment: @paropunam There are two commands in my answer, one `find` command and one `print` command. Which one of these did you run?

Comment: @paropunam Neither of those commands should cause the shell to try to execute a directory (which is what the error message indicates).